# Use file-loader and html-loader together

Tags: webpack, webpack-html-loader, webpack-file-loader

I'm working on an angular application which requires `html` files to be extracted as plain HTML files and at same time should check for any `<img src="...">` to require those images (as assets). In addition, images are based upon root path (so `/images/something.png`), they need to be resolved relatively to webpack `context` setting (the base path).

How can I achieve this? Can't get html-loader to play nicely with file-loader. Since the former outputs a JS file (with the `require` statements) and the latter expects a plain HTML file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution by myself by digging a lot into source codes of the loaders in question.

Basically, it doesn't work by default because file-loader expects a "raw" file, so if you want to output an HTML file, you need to have html source, not a JS one. However, html-loader takes an HTML file and outputs a JS file (with `require` assets and the content).

The solution was this deeply hidden and fantastic [extract-loader](https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader) which parses the JS coming out of html-loader, converts it back to plain html, the assets are still required *and* replaced even **with hash for cachebusting**.

That's perfect, you pass the output to file-loader and you finally have your html files!

**Example configuration**

In my case, my loader configuration looks like:

```
'file-loader!extract-loader!html-loader' + '?root=' + encodeURIComponent(sourcePath.toString())
```

Comment: You described the solution, but didn't post the solution. Config example?

Comment: `file-loader!extract-loader!html-loader` was enough for me. Notice that for html-loader I used also `'?root=' + encodeURIComponent(sourcePath.toString())`

Comment: Yes, I was pulling my hair to find out why the src="/url" was begin ignored until I read that root url's are ignored by default. You used ?root=, while I switched to relative url's. Both work. Thanks.

Comment: It does not work with *interpolation* flag: `file!extract!html?interpolate`.